# Media Foundation: Run simultaneously several medias?

Tags: c++, ms-media-foundation

Would there be a trick to ensure synchronous display of several identical videos (several threads) with Media Foundation ?

See

**[How to run/start a thread at a given time using Media Foundation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46301426/how-to-run-start-a-thread-at-a-given-time-using-media-foundation)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Media Foundation recording audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917256/windows-media-foundation-recording-audio)

Comment: You can play multiple media files in sync, by creating an IMFSourceReader for each file, in async mode. You can queue the samples received in OnReadSample. You can have a separate thread that will handle the queued samples, by selecting the due one(s) and send it/them to the rest of the pipeline, namely IMFSinkWriter(s) that will playback/record the samples.

Comment: And yes MFCreateAggregateSource is another option if you want/need to use IMFSession.

Comment: Would you please have a code example?

Comment: I don't manage to it, thx